# Custom Drupal 6 Module with multiple pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am trying to write my first Drupal custom module (using drupal 6).  I got the basic module working but I would like to add another page to the project.  For example, right now my module's path looks like this:  `www.mysite.com/my_custom_module`.  I would like to add another page like this:   `www.mysite.com/my_custom_module/my_sub_page`.  I've tried adding a new `.module` and `.info` file but this does not work.  I've also tried adding new items to the menu hook, like this:

my_custom_module.module:

```
function my_custom_module_menu(){
    $items  = array();
    $items['my_custom_module'] = array(
        'title' => "My Custom Module",
        'page callback' => "my_custom_module_info", 
        'access callback' => true,  
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
    );
    $items['my_custom_module/my_sub_page'] = array(
        'title' => "My Sub Page",
        'page callback' => "my_custom_module_sub_page_info", 
        'access callback' => true,  
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM, 
    );
    return $items; 

}

function my_custom_module_info(){
    $result = 'My Page URL was hit';
    return $result;
}
 function my_custom_module_sub_page_info(){
    $result = 'My Sub Page URL was hit';
    return $result;
}
```

In this example, if I go to `.../my_custom_module` it works fine.  But, if I go to `.../my_custom_module/my_sub_page`, it still load, and displays `my_custom_module`.  When I debug with a break point in each function, only `my_custom_module_info` is hit.  Not the sub page.  What am I doing wrong?  I this even the correct way to create multi pages in a module?  Just an FYI, each of these pages will have different audiences.  The first page is to allow a user to submit some form data.  The second is to allow an elevated user view the data.

Thanks

jason

Comment: Your code looks correct to me. Did you clear your menu cache?

Comment: Yes, I tried flushing all cache as well as clearing the cache in my browser.  This did not help.

Comment: Do i need to make any changes to my .info file or add a new one for the new page?

Comment: no, no need to change .info.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I did that as well.

Comment: Ha!, I cleared the menu cache again, and this time it worked.  Weird.  Thanks for your help.  If you post it as a response, Ill mark it as correct.